# Log permissions in FastAPI app middleware

Tags: fastapi

I want to add a parameter on request object when I decode JWT, and then read this parameter in my middleware to add it to my info log.
I have a permission class as follows:

```
class MyPermClass:         
    async def __call__(
             self,             
             request: Request,
     ):         
          # I decode JWT and assign it to decoded_token  
          request.user_perms = decoded_token         
          return decoded_token.get('user')
```

And I have a controller as follows:

```
@router.get(path="/some_path/")
async def get_detail(         
    id: int,         
    user=Depends(MyPermClass()),         
    db: Session = Depends(db_session),
     ):     
        # Do things...
```

And so, this is my middleware for logging request and response parameters:

```
async def set_body(request: Request, body: bytes):
    async def receive() -> Message:
        return {"type": "http.request", "body": body}

    request._receive = receive

@app.middleware("http")
async def log_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    body = await request.body()
    await set_body(request, body)
    response = await call_next(request)
    perms = request.user_perms
```

But `request.user_perms` raises `AttributeError`. How can I do that?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `request.state.user_perms` - any state for a request should go under `.state` and not directly on the `request` object. I would also be _very_ careful about doing it this way; if you don't have the `MyPermClass` as a dependency in a route, your app will break, so you've effectively created a hidden dependency between a middleware and always having to have a dependency present in your routes. Try to contain it in a middleware by itself if necessary, so that you can easily remove/reuse/readd it.